# Shell 'eval' Java process, where is the Log (if any)?

Tags: java, systemd, systemctl, catalina

*Environment: CentOS 7 |
Java: 1.8 |
Tomcat: 9*

I am starting (it fails) a webapp through *systemd (systemctl)* but I am not seeing any **Logs** outside of what I see in *journalctl -fu*, which basically just tells me "it failed".

[image]

Catalina Tomcat also does not write into catalina.out (it remains 0bytes).

**Question:** How do I get more info on why this process fails? (Java logs?)

---

--This is the code in *catalina.sh* that starts the app

```
eval $_NOHUP "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" "\"$CATALINA_LOGGING_CONFIG\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER "$JAVA_OPTS" "$CATALINA_OPTS" \
      -D$ENDORSED_PROP="\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\"" \
      -classpath "\"$CLASSPATH\"" \
      -Dcatalina.base="\"$CATALINA_BASE\"" \
      -Dcatalina.home="\"$CATALINA_HOME\"" \
      -Djava.io.tmpdir="\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\"" \
      org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start \
      >> "$CATALINA_OUT" 2>&1 "&"
```

Comment: Did you install Tomcat via apt?

Comment: No I download it with curl from https://archive.apache.org and just move the unpacked stuff into place

Comment: I would strongly recommend using your package manager. Then you just need `sudo systemctl start tomcat9.service`